# SSIS The variable cannot be found

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, dts

I want to execute package from visual studio solution

**Code:**

```
private Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package pkgPaquete;
private Application appAplicacion;

public DTSExecResult EjecucionPaquete(string str_Paquete, List < CatVariablesEtl > Vars = null) {

  DTSExecResult respuesta;
  try {
    appAplicacion = new Application();

    appAplicacion.PackagePassword = "pass";

    pkgPaquete = appAplicacion.LoadPackage(str_Paquete, null);
    foreach(CatVariablesEtl item in Vars) {
      pkgPaquete.Variables[item.str_NombreVariable.ToString()].Value = item.str_ValorVariable.ToString();
    }

    respuesta = pkgPaquete.Execute();

    return respuesta;
  } catch (Exception ex) {

    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

}
}
}
```

It stop into foreach statement just in this line it throw catch:

```
pkgPaquete.Variables[item.str_NombreVariable.ToString()].Value = item.str_ValorVariable.ToString();
```

[image]

**str_NombredeVariable value:**
[image]

**item.str_ValorVariable value:**[image]

**Parameters into package:**

[image]

Error:

> The variable cannot be found. This occurs when an attempt is made to retrieve a variable from the Variables collection on a container during execution of the package, and the variable is not there. The variable name may have changed or the variable is not being created.

I read another relationed questions but I don´t found some correct answer to my problem. Help is very appreciated. Regards

**Update:** as Hadi comment I try to use

```
var setValueParameters = new Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet>();
```

But I just get vs red mark, I need to import some reference?[image]

As the second answer of Hadi I cannot reference pkgPaquete.Variables:[image]

Comment: I suggest you inspect `pkgPaquete.Variables` at runtime and see what kind of format is required for the argument.

Comment: Parameters cannot be modified programmatically, use variables instead of them. (you can only modify variables that start with `User::` , parameters are variables but with different scope `Package::` or `project::` and cannot be modified only when building the package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First Attempt

Try removing `User::` from the variable name

```
foreach(CatVariablesEtl item in Vars) {
  pkgPaquete.Variables[item.str_NombreVariable.ToString().Replace("User::","")].Value = item.str_ValorVariable.ToString();
}
```

### Second Method to assing variables

Also try using this method to assign value to variables:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.RunTime.Variables myVars = pkgPaquete.Variables;

foreach(CatVariablesEtl item in Vars) {
  myVars[item.str_NombreVariable.ToString().Replace("User::","")].Value = item.str_ValorVariable.ToString();
}

Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult results = pkgPaquete.Execute(null, myVars, null, null, null);
```

**if using parameters, It look like that they cannot be modified programatically. Try using variables instead of them**

Comment: I try it but I get issue:  Changing the Value of a variable failed because it is a parameter variable. Parameter variables are read-only

Comment: @Gerardo what have you tried, removing `User::` or the second method?

Comment: Yes I want to remove it but I have issue: Changing the Value of a variable failed because it is a parameter variable. Parameter variables are read-only

Comment: @Gerardo i provided a new method check it out

Comment: I need to reference some there? I get vs red mark into Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet> Note: Update in my question

Comment: i apologize i found that this is another reference that `ManagedDTS.dll` it is using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll` so i don't think it will work (it is using another class)

Comment: @Gerardo i didn't find anything new, it is a shame i couldn't help. just try the second method without removing `User::` as a final attempt.

Comment: I try to import pkgPaquete.Variables as you say but I can´t, can you check my last edit in my question please?

Comment: You have to call this line after loading the package, also the package parameter doesn't starts with `User::` prefix, they starts with `Package::` prefix, Variables starts with `User::`

Comment: same error: Changing the Value of a variable failed because it is a parameter variable. Parameter variables are read-only.

Comment: It look like that parameters cannot be modified programatically. Try using variables instead of them

Comment: your last comment solved foreach problem, I  changed parameters fo variables and it pass foreach statement. Problem now is when I try to execute package at respuesta = pkgPaquete.Execute();, it return status fail

Comment: If the status is fail you have to debug your package. It looks like the problem you asked for is solved. Try debugging the package using the same variables values

Comment: I debug it and I get:  run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Derived Column of Integration Services or higher, so now I try to download sql server 2014 (SP2) to try it

Comment: @gerardo you have to add a new question and accept this answer because it solved ur issue

Comment: @Gerardo you have to accept this answer, and post a new question with the new errors. (you can read them from `pkgPaquete.errors`)